# Content not aligning to bottom of table

Tags: html, css, email, html-table

Currently working on coding for Email:

I am trying to get this button (created out of tables) to align to the bottom of the enclosing table.  At the moment it will not align and I'm not sure why.

```html
<table width="300" min-width="300" height="500" class="promo_3" align="left">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.thing.html">
        <img class="promo" alt="Promo image 2" src="http://media.campaigner.com/image1.jpg">
      </a>
      <br>
      <br>

      <h1> TRAINING </h1>
      <span valign="top" class="content">TITLE HERE</span>
      <p>TEXT HERE</p>
      <br>
      <!--Button THIS WILL NOT ALIGN TO THE BOTTOM -->

      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
        <tr>
          <td height="20">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#f55926" valign="bottom" style="padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px" align="center"><a href="http://www.thing.html" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Read More</a> 
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--Button + Social End -->


    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: technically it already is at the bottom of the table

Comment: how would I align all content but the 'button' to the top?  What currently aligns it to the bottom?  I have two of these side by side in a larger table and the content all aligns to the top in this larger table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe give this method a try:

```
    <table width="300" min-width="300" height="500" class="promo_3" align="left">
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><br>
      <br>

     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td height="200" valign="top"><a target="_blank" href="http://www.thing.html"><img class="promo" alt="Promo image 2" src="http://media.campaigner.com/image1.jpg"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="200" valign="top">

   <h1> TRAINING </h1>
      <span valign="top" class="content">TITLE HERE</span>
      <p>TEXT HERE</p>


   </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



      <br>
      <!--Button THIS WILL NOT ALIGN TO THE BOTTOM -->

      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
        <tr>
          <td height="20">
            <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#f55926" valign="bottom" style="padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px" align="center"><a href="http://www.thing.html" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Read More</a> 
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--Button + Social End -->


    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

What I have done is added one table with two rows, both the rows have specific height with content aligned top. Some email clients are notorious and might not align the code to the bottom as it is on the code, for those email clients you can use padding-top on the TD's. Hope this helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for? Just add align='left' to table containing button.

```html
<table width="300" min-width="300" height="500" class="promo_3" align="left">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://www.thing.html">
        <img class="promo" alt="Promo image 2" src="http://media.campaigner.com/image1.jpg">
      </a>
      <br>
      <br>

      <h1> TRAINING </h1>
      <span valign="top" class="content">TITLE HERE</span>
      <p>TEXT HERE</p>
      <br>
      <!--Button THIS WILL NOT ALIGN TO THE BOTTOM -->

      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
        <tr>
          <td height="20">
            <table border="0" align='left' cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
              <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#f55926" valign="bottom" style="padding: 8px 30px 8px 30px;-webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px" align="center"><a href="http://www.thing.html" target="_blank" style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;">Read More</a> 
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <!--Button + Social End -->


    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```